# Rectangle selection boundary is too thick in GIMP

Tags: 14.04, gimp

When I make a rectangular selection with GIMP 2.8.10, the actual border of the rectangle is too wide (at least 4 pixels wide). Previous versions of the GIMP had a 1-pixel-wide selection. How do I get it back?

The new, wide selection blurs the boundary, and I can't easily see what I want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it back - this is the only selection outline in GIMP 2.8. If you need precise control, you can zoom in - for example in a second view of the image.

Comment: The wide boundary is also disturbing when zoomed in. Zooming in definitely doesn't solve the problem, but it makes it less severe.

Comment: You'd zoom in until a pixel becomes larger than the outline.